# Is language a living system?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language

Think about it, the words behave like genes. Strongest words survive. Words mutate, combine, and cross. Words evolve. And we, people (with all our information carrying devices), are their environment.

Comment: Richard Dawkins would say yes, see the concept of [meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme).

Comment: What is the question here?  Are you just making a statement or are you interestied in whether the definitions of a "living system" from different philosophers may include or exclude language?

Comment: How would you even qualify "strongest words"? You mean words that are used most often? This is explicitly off topic as it stands, the question isn't anything more than 'am I right?' The body of the question is just a few conflationary and equivocating arguments for why the answer may be 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question of semantics than a question of philosophy.  Most can clearly see the similarities and differences between a biological living thing and a language.

But whether we call language a living thing or not is merely to do with how broadly we use the term "living thing" in our speech rather than related to the true essence of "language" and "living things".